# Cannot insert into table with stored generated primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I cannot insert data in table with generated stored primary key.

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `living_complex` (
  `id` bigint(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`location_id`) STORED NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_living_complex_name` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_living_complex_location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `idx_living_complex_name` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_living_complex_location_id` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `reeve`.`living_complex` (`location_id`, `name`) 
                         VALUES ('1', 'some_living_complex');
```

Error is:

> 1048: Column 'id' cannot be null

I don't have NOT NULL key-word in create statement. Why does it asks for id?

Comment: 'I don't have NOT NULL key-word in create statement' - looks like you do to me? AND what's the point of a generates field that is the same as another field?

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce your problem, what version of mysql are you on and what UI are you using.

Comment: `\`id\` bigint(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (\`location_id\`) STORED NOT NULL` - so you **do** have `NOT NULL` for `id` field

Comment: @MichaelO. hm. it's actually output from mysql workbench "copy create statement". I wasn't write it while I was creating it. Is generated field should be Not Null? I altered column as " ALTER TABLE `reeve`.`living_complex` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` BIGINT(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (location_id) STORED ;". and after this descibing it, i get as Not Null

Answer (score 0):

Got it. There was an mistake in trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `reeve`.`trg_living_complex_object_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `living_complex` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `reeve`.`object` (
        `id`,
        `object_type_id`
    )
    VALUES (
        new.id, 
        (SELECT `object_type`.`id` FROM `reeve`.`object_type` WHERE `table_name` = 'living_complex')
    );
END
```

Which should be AFTER insert. Because I don't have NEW.id (generated by expression) until I do insert.